# Grid View Sorting Arrows not getting displayed

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, sorting

I am sorting a grid view.The sorting works perfect.Now I am trying to add the sort arrows next to each header columns.I have tried almost every way, but the arrows do not get displayed in my UI.PFB my code:

CSS:

```
th .ascending a {
    background: url(images/ascArrow.gif) no-repeat;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 4px 0 15px;
}

th .descending a {
    background: url(images/descArrow.gif) no-repeat;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 4px 0 15px;
}
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void RPMData_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        if (TextData.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Customer_Name,Site_Type,Source,Destination,Latency,Jitter_Priority_Real_Time,Jitter_Real_Time,PacketLoss_Priority_Real_Time,PacketLoss_Real_Time,PacketLoss_Other_Classes from RPM", con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt1);
            con.Close();
            if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                string sortingDirection = string.Empty;
                if (direction == SortDirection.Ascending)
                {
                    direction = SortDirection.Descending;
                    RPMData.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "descending";
                    sortingDirection = "Desc";
                }
                else
                {
                    direction = SortDirection.Ascending;
                    RPMData.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "ascending";
                    sortingDirection = "Asc";
                }

                DataView sortedView = new DataView(dt1);
                sortedView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + sortingDirection;
                Session["SortedView"] = sortedView;
                RPMData.DataSource = sortedView;
                RPMData.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

//The sorting logic has 2 conditions based upon a filter applied.I have added here only the first condition

GridView tags:

```
<asp:GridView CssClass="infoTable" ID="RPMData" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Button1_Click" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="10" OnPageIndexChanging="RPMData_PageIndexChanging" AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="RPMData_Sorting" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SortedAscendingHeaderStyle-CssClass="ascending" SortedDescendingHeaderStyle-CssClass="descending">
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="ascending" />
        <Columns>
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

The `HeaderStyle.CssClass` is applied to the enitre header row `<tr class="ascending">`, not the idividual `th` cells. Change your CSS to

```
<style>
    .ascending a {
        background:url(images/ascArrow.gif) no-repeat;
        display: block;
        padding: 0 4px 0 15px;
    }

    .descending a {
        background:url(images/descArrow.gif) no-repeat;
        display: block;
        padding: 0 4px 0 15px;
    }
</style>
```

Or if you use that class elsewhere, `.ascending th a` will ensure it only affects the header rows.